# Insert Speeds for large batches

Tags: mysql, innodb, insert, java, jdbc

In my application, my INSERTs seem to be taking a major chunk of the time. I have a large number of objects in memory (~40-50,000) which i want to insert into a table.

Lets take a sample table

```
CREATE TABLE bill (
id BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY,
amount INT(11) DEFAULT 0,
bill_date DATETIME DEFAULT NOW(),
INDEX (bill_date)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Taking 3 rows as my batch size, the following are the approaches i could think of for inserting

Approach 1 - construct and fire 3 raw inserts

```
INSERT INTO bill (amount, bill_date) VALUES (10, '2012-01-01 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO bill (amount, bill_date) VALUES (20, '2012-01-02 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO bill (amount, bill_date) VALUES (40, '2013-02-05 00:00:00');
```

Approach 2 - clubbing the values into 1 query

```
INSERT INTO bill (amount, bill_date) VALUES 
(10, '2012-01-01 00:00:00'),
(20, '2012-01-02 00:00:00'),
(40, '2013-02-05 00:00:00');
```

Approach 3 - fire this query 1 time passing 6 parameters

```
INSERT INTO bill (amount, bill_date) VALUES 
(?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?);
```

Approach 4 - Fire this prepared query 3 times changing the 2 parameters each time

```
INSERT INTO bill (amount, bill_date) VALUES (?, ?);
```

Any other approaches are welcome.

My question is

**What is the quickest way to make multiple inserts in a table?**

I have read [this link on mysql insert speed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html) and [this guide to JDBC programming](http://oreilly.com/catalog/jorajdbc/chapter/ch19.html), but i'm not able to come to a conclusion.

**My case -**

Currently my table has ~ 20 columns, most of which are numbers, with a couple of varchar(60) and 1 text column. Mysql version 5.5.
Running on INNODB and has 1 index on Integer primary keys.
All the queries run in transaction.

I construct my queries from Java and use Spring JDBC to run the queries.

I am currently following Approach 3, It is taking around 10 seconds for 20,000 inserts to an empty table, not including the time it takes to construct the query.

To keep things in perspective, its taking 100-200 millis to fetch the data from the table.

**Is there something i am missing?
How do i make the inserts faster?**

Comment: Related question on Stack Overflow: [MySQL and JDBC with rewriteBatchedStatements=true](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313288/2144390)

Answer (score 3):

Consider batching your commits.
A batch size of 1024 is a good starting size.
Change batch sizes until you reach your optimum throughput.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested or would it be possible to drop indexes on the destination DB table(s) where you are inserting into, insert those into smaller batched chunks (optimal as indicated above), and then rebuild the indexes on the destination table(s) once all inserts are complete? May be something easy enough to test to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Some bulk data loading tips from mysql document is possible useful. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

You can increase insert speed by some ways:

```
- turn off autocommit
- turn off unique check
- turn off foreign check
```

Hope this help !

Comment: If turning off constraint checks (unique, foreign key, ...) be very very sure that your data does not break them or your database is in an inconsistent state from that point onwards.